# Is there any azure API by which we can push our selenium automation test results in Test Plan section of Azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have to find a solution by which we can post test results in Test Plan section of azure devops. Currently, scripts are integrated with azure pipelines but results are not appearing in Test Plan.

I have tried to do it with the help of TFS plugin but it is not showing the results in test plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rest API [Test Point – Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test-point/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). You can also check  [Test Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test-plans?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/TestPoint?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

Body example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "results": {
            "outcome": "failed"
        }
    }
]
```